# Get value in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have one function which return value in this format:

```
    li#2.ui-widget-content
    li#6.ui-widget-content
    li#12.ui-widget-content
    li#1.ui-widget-content
```

Each time I run function I get random value in the above format.

I want to get value after `li#` in jQuery

Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with your situation, but, it seems like what your doing could have been more easily/efficiently accomplished using something like `var theID = $('li').attr('id');`. Like I said, I'm not sure what you're doing, just seems, like, wrong... you know?

Comment: Kyle is correct. Why don't you provide a little more context?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will return everything past the 3rd character (#).

```
var value = "li#2.ui-widget-content";
var result = value.substr(3);

alert(result);
```

[substr Function Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp)